# SOLVED - Cron autorun config help please

Tags: cron

I had tried the starter pack and ran into a bunch of problems with it.  It was already set up to make cron run automatically.  After scrapping the starter pack and just installing Drupal 7 and then CiviCRM, cron doesn't run automatically and I can't find any documentation that makes any sense to a non-unix admin like me for creating some type of configuration or modifying a config file to make this happen.  Can someone please point me to instructions that are fairly easy to understand?  Gracias.

Comment: The reason that the documentation is hard to follow for setting up cron is that there's no one way to do it.  It's very much dependent on whether you have shell access (aka SSH), you're using CPanel, etc.  If you post details of your hosting environment (as in, how are you trying to set up cron?) and examples of what has NOT worked, people can give more help!

Comment: Hi Rod!  You've marked this question as "solved", but you haven't indicated which answer solved it, which makes it harder for other people to take advantage of what you've learned.  Sharing that information is what motivates people to answer questions!  Please check the "correct answer" checkbox next to the correct answer, or post your own answer and mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid setting up cron is a bit technical.  Perhaps your hosting company could help you get started?

You can find full instructions here: [Managing Scheduled Jobs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-Command-lineSyntaxforRunningJobs)

Comment: They told me I had to set up a cron job for every single event, but it seems that was not the case for the starter pack.  :/

Comment: For simpler sites one cron job is fine. This will then run all of your scheduled jobs. You only need multiple cron jobs if your needs are more complex.

Comment: Thanks William. That's good to know. I will try to figure out how to create whatever the single cron job is.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: It seems that I missed the database civicrm_install_canary.  That one was still MyISAM.  I used "ALTER TABLE civicrm_install_canary ENGINE=InnoDB;" and that seemed to have fixed it.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear that you've got it fixed.

Comment: It seems the cron issue is still not resolved.  I have read every single thread I can find on the Internet about setting up cron for civiCRM on Drupal and tried every single example given, and I STILL cannot get civiCRM cron jobs to run automatically. This is making me crazy.  And it doesn't seem to be a permissions issue, because I can run it manually with the same credentials.  HELP!

Comment: Sorry to hear you are still having trouble. I would suggest you post a new question with full details of what you have done and what the problem is. Perhaps link back to this question if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Easycron. There is a tiny cost but works quite well with Civicrm https://www.easycron.com/cron-job-tutorials/how-to-set-up-cron-job-for-civicrm